# Dict: get() not returning 0 if dict value contains None

Tags: python

python dict if a key having value None and when called get() returns NoneType

`ex_dict = {"test" : None}
ex_dict.get('test', 0)`

In above example it should return 0 but it wont.

Can any explain why it behave like that.

Comment: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) state that `get` only returns the default value if the key is not present in the dict. In your example, `"test"` is in the dict, so `get` won't return the default `0`.

Comment: Both answers and the comment are already all correct and answer your question. However, I assume you wanted to explicit try to unset the "test" item in your ex_dict and tried that assigning None to it. If you really WANT that you have to use `ex_dict.pop('test', None)` which is smart method of unsetting it when it exists and having no error otherwise.

Comment: Please try `ex_dict.get('test', 0) or 0` if you want absolutely not None result

Answer (score 11):

No, it shouldn't. If `test` key is not found in the `ex_dict` dictionary it should return `0`. But, because it exists it will return `None`

```
ex_dict = {"test" : None}
print type(ex_dict.get('test', 0))  # <class 'NoneType'>, 'test' exist, return None

print(ex_dict.get('hello', 0))  # prints 0, 'hello' isn't a key inside ex_dict
```

Comment: You want to do `ex_dict.get("test", 0) or 0`. If the key doesn't exist or is set to None this will give you 0

Comment: Correct. Or even simpler `ex_dict.get("test") or 0`.

Answer (score 6):

The `None` response in `ex_dict.get('test', 0)` is ok because the "test" key exists and has `None` value. For instance, if you try the same with `ex_dict.get("non_existing_key", 0)` it returns 0.